# Multiline text file, how to put into an environment variable

Tags: batch-file, multiline

i have a file called file.txt which contains:

```
     this is line one ^
     this is line two ^
     this is the last line
```

how can i put that into an env var?

i can do this from a batch file:
test.bat

```
    set LF=^
    [blank line]
    [blank line]
    rem two blank lines needed above
    set multi=Line 1!LF!Line 2!LF!Last line
    echo !multi!
```

this outputs three lines:

```
      Line 1
      Line 2
      Last line
```

so how can i get file.txt into envvar inside a batch file?

Comment: is the carat ^ really in the file, or is that a placeholder for a CRLF?  I'm assuming this is a windows machine.

Comment: The caret is really in the file, it's the way to create a variable which contains one linefeed character. `set LF=^` followed by two empty lines

Comment: thanks jeb for the clarification

Comment: yes rob, this is a windows machine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As dbenham said, it can be done also with for/f but it's a bit more complicated.

The simple 80% solution is

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "var="
set LF=^


rem *** Two empty lines are required for the linefeed
FOR /F "delims=" %%a in (myFile.txt) do (
  set "var=!var!!LF!%%a"
)
echo !var!
```

But it fails with:
- If a line is blank it will be skipped
- If a line begins with `;` the EOL-character
- If a line contains `!` (and carets)

But then you could use a bit more complex solution

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL DisableDelayedExpansion
set "all="
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`"findstr /n ^^ aux1.txt"`) do (
    set "line=%%a"
    SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "line=!line:#=#S!"
    set "line=!line:*:=!"
    for /F "delims=" %%p in ("!all!#L!line!") do (
        ENDLOCAL
        set "all=%%p"
    )
)
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
if defined all (
set "all=!all:~2!"
set ^"all=!all:#L=^

!"
set "all=!all:#S=#!"
)
echo !all!
```

What the code do?
First, the `findstr /n ^^` will prepend each line with a line number and a colon, like

```
1:My first Line
2:; beginning with a semicolon
3:
4:there was an empty line
```

This solves the problem of empty lines and also the standard EOL-character `;` can be ignored.
To get the content of the line, the value is set to a variable while delayed expansion is disabled, this solves the problem with `!` and `^` characters.

To remove the line number and the colon, the delayed expansion will be enabled (no, a delim of `:` can't solve it).

Then all `#` are replaced with `#S`, this will be done first, as after the prefix removing the line could be empty and the replacement would fail.
But why I replace it?
That's because I can't insert the linefeeds here, as the following FOR/F would fail with embedded linefeeds,
so I only add *linefeed marker* (in this case I use `#L`), but the content of the file could contain also a `#L`, but by replacing all `#` with `#S` all markers are unique.

After the marker, there is the problem to close/disable the delayed expansion with an `endlocal`, but preserve the content of the modified `all` and `line` variable.
This is done with the `FOR/F-endlocal` trick, as the `%%p` can transport content behind the `endlocal` barrier.

Then after reading the complete file, I check if the `all` is defined, as it would be empty for an empty file.
Then the first *linefeed marker* `#L` will be removed, and all other markers are replaced with a real linefeed character.
Then the sharp safer `#S` will be reverted to `#`.

That's all, so even this solution is obviously...

Comment: +1, I started going down the FOR /F route, but then I thought to myself, "Why am I doing all this work?" :-)

Comment: very funny :)  but then i have come as a lowly grasshopper only wanting to learn the intracsies of DOS... and am humbled that you would give it the old college try... but many thanks for all of your work, here and abroad! i will stay on the path

Comment: this of course is brilliant! as my source file (aux) is really an html file that needs to be inserted into an sql record (and the source contains ! in the first line). so +2 for that insightful bit of code! so now i just have to check the size of the file to make sure that it is under the 8k limit, if not then i can split up the !all! into !all1! !all2!, etc.. about half of my files are 8k-30K so probably max is four or five !all! var's. thanks for sharing

Answer (score 3):

You were almost there. You need to read each line of text and then append the line plus a line feed to the variable.

FOR /F could be used, but it doesn't play well with delayed expansion if the content contains `!` characters. It is also awkward to preserve blank lines and awkward to disable the EOL option.

A simpler solution is to use SET /P to read the lines. The limitations with this technique are:

1) It trims trailing control characters from each line

2) The file must use Windows standard line terminators of carriage return, line feed. It will not work with Unix style line feed.

3) It is limited to reading 1023 bytes per line (not including the line terminator characters)

Bear in mind that an environment variable can only hold a little less than 8 kbytes of data. So you are limited to only loading a very small file into a variable with this technique.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set LF=^


:: Two blank lines above needed for definition of LF - do not remove
set file="test.txt"
set "var="
for /f %%N in ('find /c /v "" ^<%file%') do set lineCnt=%%N
<%file% (
  for /l %%N in (1 1 %lineCnt%) do (
    set "ln="
    set /p "ln="
    set "var=!var!!ln!!lf!"
  )
)
set var
```

Comment: +1, As it's the simplest way and in the most cases you don't need more

Comment: well i think that i might push the limit with this as my file sometimes exceed 8k, so i will have to parse the one file into two or more variables..so its off to DOSville where i will attempt the impossible :)