# using mvn dependency:build-classpath output file has line larger than 8192 characters

Tags: batch-file, maven-dependency-plugin

I'm trying to get the classpath with maven to a file, using the command:

```
mvn dependency:build-classpath -Dmdep.ouputFile=test.txt
```

but the result is in one line separated with ';'.
 The problem is when I try to read the line with windows batch I'm not getting results because the line is larger than 8192 characters.
can I get the results in multiple lines instead of one?
If there is a way to use /P as @Squashman suggested but getting the parts based on the delimiter it will be great, otherwise, I prefer to get the dependencies list as multiple lines by the maven command if there is any.

Comment: I know we discussed reading files with lines longer then 8192 bytes on DosTips.com.  I would assume it has been discussed on StackOverFlow as well.  I will search for the answer, but I would suggest you search as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File rewriting: One line is greater than variable's max size. Workaround?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18091056/file-rewriting-one-line-is-greater-than-variables-max-size-workaround)

Comment: And here is where we talked about it on [DosTips.com](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4945)

Comment: @Squashman thanks for the suggestion. I edit the Q.

Answer (score 0):

Splitting up the long line in file `test.txt` is an easy to achieve task with using [JREPL.BAT](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) written by **Dave Benham** which is a batch file / JScript hybrid to run a regular expression replace on a file using JScript.

Download the ZIP file containing **JREPL.BAT** and extract this batch file into directory of your batch file. Add to your batch file the following lines to replace all semicolons in `test.txt` by carriage return + line-feed.

```
call "%~dp0jrepl.bat" ";" "\r\n" /XSEQ /F test.txt /O -
```