# How to set an env variable with multiline file content in windows command prompt

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, environment-variables, multiline

I have a file say `my-file.dat` which has multiple lines. I want to set an env variable say `MYVAR` that will contain the content of my-file.dat.
That is, in windows command prompt, the output of `type my-file.dat` be same as the output of `echo %MYVAR%` and **with new-line preserved**.

In RHEL/MAC, it is typically done like this `export MYVAR=$(cat my-file.dat)`, but how do I do the similar in windows command prompt (not really interested in powershell, but feel free to share examples it might be my backup option)

Following the answer of this Stackoverflow question [Multiline text file, how to put into an environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10624240/1029599) I could get a variable to hold the content of my-file.dat. But this variable's scope seems to be the batch file. Even though I run the batch file from the command prompt, I don't see the batch-file's variable is available in the command prompt.

I tried `set /P MYVAR=<my-file.dat`  , but this sets only the first line whereas I want all lines when I echo MYVAR

Pls help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The technique you use requires delayed expansion, which is not enabled by default. So the code issues `setlocal enableDelayedExpansion`. But that localizes environment changes. When the script ends there is an implicit `endlocal`, and the environment is restored to what existed before the `setlocal`.

The simplest solution is to run the script in a session where delayed expansion is already enabled so that you can remove `setlocal enableDelayedExpansion`. You can do this simply by running
`cmd /v:on` from your command line before executing your script.

There is another simple, but ugly option. The implicit endlocal does not occur if your script has a fatal syntax error (I consider this to be a bug in cmd.exe). So you can put the following at the end of your script:

```
:: Your current script goes here.
:: I'm assuming your script falls through to the end and does not use EXIT /B

call :fatalErr 2>nul

:fatalErr
if
```

But I discourage you from using this technique if you might be executing your script multiple times - your dead environments will begin to pile up.

Also - please remember that variables are limited to ~8191 characters - your script will fail if the file you are trying to capture exceeds the limit. This is a hard limit of cmd.exe

**Update**

You could put the `cmd /v:on` command within your script if you add the /K option. The IF statement tests if delayed expansion is enabled or not. If not, then it reruns the script via cmd.exe with the /K option and /V:ON.

```
@echo off
if "!!" neq "" cmd /v:on /k "%~f0"
:: rest of your script goes here.
```